# ruby server "Bundler couldnt find some gems" bundler will not install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have cloned a 1.8.7 rails app locally and I am trying to run the ruby server, but when i type "ruby server" i receive the following error:

```
./../config/../config/preinitializer.rb:18: Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`? (RuntimeError)
from ./../config/boot.rb:28:in `load'
from ./../config/boot.rb:28:in `preinitialize'
from ./../config/boot.rb:10:in `boot!'
from ./../config/boot.rb:124
from server:2:in `require'
from server:2
```

So I then tried to install the bundler via "gem install bundler" but received this error:

```
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5 
1 gem installed
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/json-    1.7.7/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_intern2
  Referenced from: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

...and it will not run "bundle install"

```
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
```

I am currently running 3.2.12 rails, do i need to switch to an earlier version? I have RVM installed. I am fairly new at this so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've used an old rails app, but don't you want ```ruby script/server```?

Comment: Im running it from the /script directory

Comment: what is your patch version of ruby 1.8.7? The release guides of Rails 3.2 states, "Note that Ruby 1.8.7 p248 and p249 have marshaling bugs that crash Rails."

Comment: Its p371. But thanks for checking that out.

Comment: Try running `rvm get head && rvm reload` in your app repo. Then try installing bundler. Also do `bundler -v` and tell us the version.

Comment: gem bundle install seemed to go off without a hitch, but now I have a different issue. When i run "rails s" from the correct directory. I get: Usage: rails new APP_PATH, followed by a bunch of terminal commands. I think I am missing a large piece of the puzzle, and I am going to do some more research so I dont waste anyones time, but thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing 1.8.7 is your ruby version, and not rails version despite you claiming it is. Or are you trying to run a 1.8.7 rails app on your current rails version? If so, not a good idea.
First of all, when starting your server the correct syntax is `rails server` or `rails s` for short.

This is a problem with RVM. **What is your RVM version? What is your operating system?** There is a known problem with RVM and OSX Snow Leopard. Try checking your ruby version (`ruby -v`) and make sure just one version is installed, and bundle install again to update after `rvm use 1.9.3`.

Also, make sure the rvm code in your bash_profile (`/home/$USER/.bash_profile`) is correct when starting a new shell.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are correct, i meant 1.8.7 ruby version, i checked via "ruby -v" and it is currently using 1.8.7. My rvm version is 1.19.6 and I am using OSX 10.8.3.